# Find a formula for the Marginal Density Function

Tags: probability, random-variables

Continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ have joint density function:

$$
f_X,_Y(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{6x+3y^2}{4},  & \text{if 0 $\le$ x $\le$ 1 and 0 $\le$ y $\le$ 1 } \\[2ex]
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

$(a)$ Find a formula for the marginal density function $f_X(x)$. $\\$

What I have tried is the following to "cancel out the y":

$$ \int_{y=0}^{y=1} \frac{6x+3y^2}4 dy $$

The trouble I am having with this integral is how do I take out the **x** part to the outside of the integral?

I thought about $ \frac{6x+3y^2}{4} = \frac{3(2x+y^2)}{4} = \frac{3}{4}{(2x+y^2)}{} $ but then where do I go from here?

Comment: $ \int_{y=0}^{y=1} \frac{6x+3y^2}4 dy = 6x \cdot \int_{y=0}^{y=1} \frac{1}4 dy+\int_{y=0}^{y=1} \frac{3y^2}4 dy =6x \frac{1}4  + \frac{1}4 $$

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of the sum rule. That proved to be helpful. I got: $\frac{3x}2$ +$\frac{1}4$

Answer (score 1):

Just integrate $\frac{3(2x+y^2)}{4}$ wrt $y$ as $y$ goes from 0 to 1. You'll get the answer $\frac{6x+1}{4}$, which is $f_X(x)$.